# Mistake in proof of chain rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, chain-rule

I saw proof of chain rule and I must say that I don't understand one key step.

Here is the proof:
Consider function $f(x)$ and tangent $t.$ Let $\frac{dy}{dx}$ be slope of a tangent line in the point $A(a, f(a)).$ Consider another point, $B(a + \Delta{x}, f(a + \Delta{x}).$ Then slope of a secant line AB is $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}.$ Here is of course $dx = \Delta{x}.$ We can now assume that $dy - \Delta{y} = \epsilon.$ From here is easy to see that $\Delta y = f'(a) \cdot \Delta x - \epsilon$

Finally let $y = f(g(x)), u =  g(x)$ and $g(a) = b.$ Then $\Delta y = f'(b) \cdot \Delta u - \epsilon_1, \Delta u = g'(a) \cdot \Delta x - \epsilon_2.$

Combining this together we get $\Delta y = f'(b) \cdot (g'(a) \cdot \Delta x - \epsilon_2) - \epsilon_1.$

We can divide both sides by $\Delta x$: $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = f'(b) \cdot g'(a) - \frac{\epsilon_2}{\Delta x} \cdot f'(b) - \frac{\epsilon_1}{\Delta x}.$

**Now, if $\Delta x \rightarrow 0,$ then also $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\Delta x}, \frac{\epsilon_2}{\Delta x} \rightarrow 0$** (*) 
I don't understand this part, why exactly we can conclude that?

Proof finished with ...From here using (*) we get $\frac{dy}{dx} = f'(b) \cdot g'(a).$[image]

Comment: Should it be $\epsilson \times \Delta x$?

Comment: I think not. I am wondering how $\frac{\epsilon}{\Delta x} \rightarrow 0$... We know that $\epsilon \rightarrow 0, \Delta x \rightarrow 0.$ So we (naively?) get $\frac{0}{0}.$ It should be true because $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = f'(a) - \frac{\epsilon}{\Delta x}.$ Experimentally, when $\Delta x \rightarrow 0,$ secant goes to tangent, therefore $\frac{\epsilon}{\Delta x}.$ But this looks very confusing

Comment: I was thinking $\Delta  y = f'(a) \Delta x + \epsilon \Delta x$ then $\epsilon \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$

Comment: How? That would solve all problems but I get $\Delta y = dy - \epsilon \iff$ $\Delta y = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot dx - \epsilon \iff$ $ \Delta y = f'(a) \Delta x - \epsilon.$

Comment: As I understand it $\frac{\Delta y}{Delta x} = f'(a) + \epsilon$ then multiply by $\Delta x$ other than that I have no other suggestion.

Comment: In your way, $\epsilon \neq |dy - \Delta y|,$ your $\epsilon$ is difference between slopes of tangent and secant. That is, I think, correct but I am confused with original epsilon. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I am stupid... $\frac{\epsilon}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy - \Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{\Delta x} + \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$ So of course this thing, $|e|,$ will go to $0.$ But, it is confusing, without that fraction trick, why $e$ shrinks faster then $\Delta x$.